# Is there any alternative method for Cursor in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Curing_log_data] 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @Rdatetime AS Datetime
DECLARE @Barcode AS Varchar(15)
DECLARE @Cavity AS Varchar(5)
DECLARE @IPLH AS Float
DECLARE @IPRH AS Float
DECLARE @ITLH AS Float
DECLARE @ITRH AS Float
DECLARE @PTLH AS Float
DECLARE @PTRH AS Float
DECLARE @SPLH AS Float
DECLARE @SPRH AS Float
DECLARE @MachineID AS Varchar(15)
DECLARE @ShiftID AS Varchar(5)
DECLARE @C_Flag AS Int


DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD

FOR

select TOP (10000) * from [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend with(NOLOCK) order by Rdatetime asc

OPEN @Mycursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO 
@Rdatetime,@Barcode,@Cavity,@IPLH,@IPRH,@ITLH,@ITRH,@PTLH,@PTRH,@SPLH,@SPRH,@MachineID,@ShiftID,@C_Flag
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.Curing_Trend (Rdatetime, Barcode, Cavity, IPLH, IPRH, ITLH, ITRH, PTLH, PTRH, SPLH, SPRH, MachineID, ShiftID)
            values(@Rdatetime,@Barcode,@Cavity,@IPLH,@IPRH,@ITLH,@ITRH,@PTLH,@PTRH,@SPLH,@SPRH,@MachineID,@ShiftID)

            Update [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend SET C_Flag = 0 where Rdatetime = @Rdatetime and Barcode = @Barcode

            FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
            INTO @Rdatetime,@Barcode,@Cavity,@IPLH,@IPRH,@ITLH,@ITRH,@PTLH,@PTRH,@SPLH,@SPRH,@MachineID,@ShiftID,@C_Flag
        END
        CLOSE @MyCursor
        DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
        Delete from [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend  where C_Flag =0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            EXEC [dbo].[sp_InsertErrorDetails]
            Return 2
        END CATCH
    END
```

This is my procedure for transferring data from one server to another server, since there is about millions of data cursor is not effective.

Please can anyone suggest alternate way to do instead of cursor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to transfer the whole table, or just subset of data?

Comment: Im Transfering 100000 data from one table to another. it takes huge time when running in cursor.

Comment: if you are wanting to transfer the whole table, then use bcp in/out. if you are wanting to transfer a subset of data, what keys are the PK/clustering key?

Comment: Dear @Greg im transfering data from one table to another table with use of linked server. so i cannot use BCP ,

Comment: there is no PK in table

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes, you can use BCP easily, that is what it is designed to do - bulk copy data locally or remotely.  But are you looking to transfer the whole table, or only a subset of rows?  What is your end goal?  Also, the source table, is it necessary to set `C_Flag = 0` ?   The source table must have indexes, what indexes exist on the source table?

Comment: Yes I want to transfer whole data from    table A to Table B for every 15 minutes

Comment: after transferring data i have to clean up my table A so i am using C_Flag =0 and deleting it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Insert` and `delete` by batch like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Curing_Trend (Rdatetime, Barcode, Cavity, 
IPLH, IPRH, ITLH, ITRH, PTLH, PTRH, SPLH, SPRH, MachineID, ShiftID)      
    SELECT TOP (10000) 
        t.Rdatetime, t.Barcode, t.Cavity, t.IPLH,
        t.IPRH, t.ITLH, t.ITRH, t.PTLH, t.PTRH,
        t.SPLH, t.SPRH, t.MachineID, t.ShiftID 
    FROM
        [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend ct  
    ORDER BY
        Rdatetime ASC

; WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT TOP 10000 *
   FROM [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend ct  
   ORDER BY Rdatetime ASC
)
DELETE FROM cte
```

Comment: This would cause issues if new rows were inserted between the time the INSERT completed and DELETE statement started, you could potentially delete the new row(s), but they weren't inserted.

Answer (score 0):

With `OUTPUT` clause you can do it in one query. You can also filter by C_Flag if you want.

```
; WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT TOP 10000 *
   FROM [10.65.84.4].[CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend ct  
   ORDER BY Rdatetime ASC
)
DELETE
FROM cte
OUTPUT Rdatetime, Barcode, Cavity, IPLH, IPRH, ITLH, ITRH, PTLH, PTRH, SPLH, SPRH, MachineID, ShiftID
INTO [CEAT].dbo.Curing_Trend (Rdatetime, Barcode, Cavity, IPLH, IPRH, ITLH, ITRH, PTLH, PTRH, SPLH, SPRH, MachineID, ShiftID)
```